# How do you calculate the mean / sum of particular columns of a nested list column using purr's map function

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I'm trying to use purr to summarize a particular column of a nested list column.

```
library(tidyverse)
z <- tibble(name = c("Bill","Bill","Bill","Sue","Sue"), grade =c(90L,95L,70L,100L,98L), time=c(10L,11L,10L,15L,16L))

summary <- z %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  nest %>% 
  mutate(n = map_int(data,nrow)) %>% 
  mutate(avg = map(data$grade,mean)) %>% 
  mutate(ttl_time = map(data$time, sum))
```

When I run this I get an error:: Column `y` must be length 3 (the number of rows) or one, not 2

My target output is:

```
name      data     n      avg      ttl_time

Bill     [3x3]     3      92        31

Sue      [2x3]     2      99        31
```

When I remove the last two mutate function the script works as anticipated. This leads me to believe that I'm not isolating the grade and time columns within the data column, but I can figure out what I'm doing wrong?

I watched this r studio video and I believe I'm doing the same thing I saw in the video. [Working with List Columns](https://rstudio.com/resources/videos/how-to-work-with-list-columns/)

Answer (score 1):

```
z %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(n = map_int(data, nrow),
         avg = map_dbl(data, ~ mean(.x$grade)),
         ttl_time = map_dbl(data, ~ sum(.x$time)))

# # A tibble: 2 x 5
#   name  data                 n   avg ttl_time
#   <chr> <list>           <int> <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1 Bill  <tibble [3 × 2]>     3    85       31
# 2 Sue   <tibble [2 × 2]>     2    99       31
```

The formula notation with `~` is a shortcut for e.g. `function(.x) mean(.x$grade)`

---

OP's error indeed stems from the fact that `map` cannot iterate directly over each `grade` element of the `data` list, at least not with this syntax.

`data$grade` is understood as an element of the list `data` that has name `grade`, and there is no such element.

This alternative syntax might help understand how this is achievable:

```
z %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(n = map_int(data, nrow),
         avg = map_dbl(map(data, "grade"), mean),
         ttl_time = map_dbl(map(data, "time"), sum))
```

where `map(data, "grade")` extracts each `grade` component from the elements  of the list column `data`.

Though this is, in my opinion, less readable than the first suggestion.